# Using SHA hashing to allow for longer bcrypt inputs

Tags: cryptography, bcrypt

I'm looking at the various bcrypt implementations across several languages and noticing the character limitation across most - specifically, the 72 character maximum that node-bcrypt, php's bcrypt, and py-bcrypt all exhibit.

What are the advantages and disadvantages if an application were to run user input through, say, a SHA-256 or SHA-512 checksum beforehand to enable longer inputs for bcrypt?

Comment: bcrypt is intended for passwords. You're really worried about exceeding 72-character passwords?

Comment: @MattBall I'm not worried, I'm actually quite curious as to the implications.  Of course it rarely will be required, but this is something that came up recently in a discussion and I'd like to learn if it's as problematic as I suspect.

Comment: Exact duplicate on security.SE: [Pre-hash password before applying bcrypt to avoid restricting password length](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6623/pre-hash-password-before-applying-bcrypt-to-avoid-restricting-password-length)

Comment: @CodeInChaos Thanks for the link!  I wasn't aware of the question being asked over there. I'll flag this as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The CLI application found [here](http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/) is limited to 8-56 "characters" inclusive (it's C, so a character can be anything I suppose). Heaven knows why you would create limits for something that you feed into a password based key derivation function afterwards (which almost certainly will take unlimited input).

An additional secure hash with sufficient strength and output size will not do anything to degrade security.

Encode the result to hexadecimals before feeding it to a bcrypt library, which is almost certainly expecting a String (don't get struck by the "odd" 00h byte). You might as well use SHA-256, I don't think a few bits more or less will make a difference if you feed it into bcrypt afterwards. Otherwise you may be forced to use base64.

Finally, try not to get into this situation, performing non-standard cryptography is almost certainly a bad thing.